# How to query Verisign Whois data in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, whois

This says that [Getting a full copy of the WHOIS database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468628/getting-a-full-copy-of-the-whois-database?rq=1) is good to scan whois data for my class assignment.

How do I do so with vb.net?

Do I use a webclient? What's the host? Get or post?

I tried

```
http://registrar.verisign-grs.com/webwhois-ui/rest/whois?q=nationaltirewarehouse.org&tld=org&type=domain
```

followed by

```
page = wc.DownloadString(URL)
```

it works for .com and .net but not for .org.

Comment: What do you mean by "it works for .com and .net but not for .org"? What does working vs. not working look like? Do you get error messages? Or just no results?

Comment: I cannot look up .org domains with this code. Actually, how do you automate whoising anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Verisign does not offer `whois` services for *.org* domains, they only give `whois` data for *.com* and *.net* domains. The official *.org* `whois` database is controlled by [whois.pir.org](http://whois.pir.org).