# How to query ASN for a known IP address with GeoIP on Django?

Tags: python, django, gis, geodjango, geoip

I'm using Django 1.73 on Python 2.7.

How can I query the ASN for a known IP address using GeoIP Django?

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
g = GeoIP()
g.city('72.14.207.99') #returns the city
g.country('google.com') #returns the country
```

how can I query the asn with Django? (have installed the ASN binaries on GEO_PATH)

**Edit** 
I've researched and found there exist a Python package PyGeoIP,
In [documentation](http://pygeoip.readthedocs.org/en/v0.3.2/getting-started.html) there exist an ASN lookup but I don't know how to call with GeoDjango directly than using this package.

Comment: You could query whois servers.

Comment: I don't prefer external calls.

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468628/getting-a-full-copy-of-the-whois-database

Comment: Oh not whois, but ipinfo.io provides a light json api. I'm asking if this is possible with MaxMind's GeoLiteASN binaries?

Comment: I don't know, check their documentation, they should have some code samples.

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy to use pygeoIp it is pretty straightforward.

First download the ASN database from [GeoIP](http://download.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/asnum/GeoIPASNum.dat.gz) then install `pygeoip` by

```
pip install pygeoip
```

then

```
>>> gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('/path/to/GeoIPASNum.dat')
>>> gi.org_by_name('cnn.com')
'AS5662 Turner Broadcasting'
```

or

```
>>> gi.org_by_addr("90.223.167.43")
u'AS5607 BSKYB-BROADBAND-AS'
```

If you do not want to download any database you can use [pyip2asn](https://github.com/oneryalcin/pyip2asn)

```
In [1]:import pyip2asn

In [2]:# Generate ASN Description Dictionary in order to speed up the IPv4 to ASN lookup.

In [3]: asn_dict = pyip2asn.get_asn_dictionary()
In [4]: pyip2asn.ip2asn("8.8.8.8",asn_dict)
Out[4]: (15169, u'GOOGLE - Google Inc.')
```